# How to Send, Read and Delete SMS in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sms

How to delete an SMS from the inbox in Android programmatically using flutter? anyone can help? Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 3):

yes there is library available for this

Sending SMS

```
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() {
  SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
  String address = someAddress();
  ...
  sender.sendSms(new SmsMessage(address, 'Hello flutter!'));
}
```

Receiving SMS

```
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() {
  SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
  receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body));
}
```

Deleting SMS

```
SmsRemover smsRemover = SmsRemover();
<boolean value> = await smsRemover.removeSmsById(sms.id, _smsThread.threadId)
```

for more deteial checkout this page.
[sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained) .

Comment: for listening incoming SMS

Answer (score 2):

The above `'package:sms/sms.dart'` is no longer up to date.
You can use the [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony) package instead.

**For example, sending an SMS:**
Import the telephony package:

```
import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';
```

Retrieve the singleton instance of **telephony** by calling:

```
final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
```

Add the following permission in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

And then, to send the SMS directly from your app:

```
telephony.sendSms(
    to: "1234567890",
    message: "May the force be with you!"
);
```

In the above documentation, they tell you how to also read SMS messages and more (didn't see how to delete though).

Comment: How to delete messages with telephony?

Answer (score 1):

this answer as your comment (for listening incoming SMS ).

**Getting all SMS messages #**

import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

```
void main() {
  SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
  List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.getAllSms;

}
```

This list (messages) return all sms.